# How to show only non-bold text of toast

Tags: uwp, windows-10, toast

In Windows 10 and with Visual Studio 2017 I try to send a toast of UWP app which shows only regular text not bold one. According to the MSDN `ToastTemplateType.ToastText01` should show regular text but doesn't.

How can I make all regular text toast message?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ToastTemplateType toastTemplate = ToastTemplateType.ToastText01;

    XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastTemplate);

    XmlNodeList toastTextElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");

    toastTextElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("content content content content content content content content content content "));

    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're writing a UWP app, you should be using [the UWP ToastGeneric toast templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts).

However, regardless of that, you can **not** have a toast that only has non-bold text. The first text element (the title) will always be displayed as bold in builds 16299 and higher of Windows 10. That is simply the new visual style of toasts.